# How to change html element or pass data based on the page in AngularJs routing?

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a component called `<bradcam-area>`, this section should be displaying titles of each page. I thought of using

So here is the HTML:

```
<div class="bradcam_area bradcam_bg_1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="bradcam_text text-center">
                    <h3> Change this based on the page </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the TS file:

```
export class BradcamAreaComponent implements OnInit {

  // Titles
  titles = {
    about: 'About Me',
    services: 'Here is what I provide',
    portfolio: 'My awesome work here',
    contact: 'Get in touch'
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I researched can't figure out what should I do.

[image: Screenshot of the website]

here is the about page for example:

```
<app-header></app-header>
    <bradcam-area></bradcam-area>
    <!-- You can add extra content under this comment -->

    <about-area></about-area>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: FYI, AngularJS refers to the old project, aka AngularJS **1.x**. All versions after (Angular 2,4,5,6,7,8,9) are simply referred to as Angular (without the JS). AngularJS and Angular are two quite different frameworks and shouldn't be confused.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `*ngIf` (seeing your own solution), you could simply do this :

```
<h3> {{ titles[router.url] }} </h3>
```

Much more compact, fast and easier to maintain and update.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I used the ngIf method `<h3 *ngIf="router.url === '/about'">`

and in the `<bradcam-area>` Ts file I added these

```
  private router: Router;

  constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
```

and here is the Final HTML template of `<bradcam-area>`

```
<div class="bradcam_area bradcam_bg_1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="bradcam_text text-center">
                    <h3 *ngIf="router.url === '/about'"> {{ titles.about }} </h3>
                    <h3 *ngIf="router.url === '/services'"> {{ titles.services }} </h3>
                    <h3 *ngIf="router.url === '/portfolio'"> {{ titles.portfolio }} </h3>
                    <h3 *ngIf="router.url === '/contact'"> {{ titles.contact }} </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing `this.router = router` in the constructor, you can simply go `constructor(private router: Router){ }`